# Can I convert obj file to h file C++?

Tags: c++, .obj, borland-c++

I tried to modify an old application.  This application was programmed in Borland C++, and the last programmer lost the header files (.h).  I can not compile the program with new modifications. The folder of the application project contains the last object files (.obj).

My question is:

Can I convert those object files to header files?

I tried to convert the files using `obj2opengl.pl`, but it did not work.

Comment: ***Can I convert those object files to h files?*** No.

Comment: ***I try to convert the files using obj2opengl.pl but it does not work.*** That is a different type of obj file. Has nothing to do with c++.

Comment: This would be called "decompiling". It can be 'done', using the right tools, fsvo 'done'. In my experience, it's limited at best.. usually better to get a gist and it definitely *won't* result in the 'original header files'.

Comment: If you don't have the source code that was used to compile the object files, then you will have to reverse engineer the object files, such as with a tool like IDA, and then manually create new header files that are compatible with the existing object files.

Comment: All of the content of all four of those comments should be in the answer section.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, I think it is better try for other way and make a new header files.